# For $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, sow the Maclaurin series for $(1+x)^m$

Tags: real-analysis

For $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, sow the Maclaurin series for $(1+x)^m$ is

$\sum_{n=0}^{m} \frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}x^n$

I think i followed the correct procedure but I don't know how to account for the M values in the denominator or how to see the pattern need to write the expansion in sigma notation.It feels like i skipped steps in the end which would reveal (m-n) for each part of the expansion.[image]

Comment: What you have there is correct.  I wouldn't bother to multiply out (m)(m-1)(m-2) etc. as you have done as it actually takes you away from showing that that equals $\frac{m!}{(m-k)!}$ as you hope to show.

Comment: LATEX !!! and note that by definition of the [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) : $(1+x)^m = \sum_{n=0}^m {m \choose n} x^n$. what needs a proof is that $ {m \choose n} = \frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}$. $\quad$ [the Taylor series theorem that if $f$ is real-analytic and if the series converges then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Approximation_and_convergence) $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k$ applied to $f(x) = (1+x)^m$ being one possible (but complicated) proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is mostly correct.  There is one error.

First, not an error, but I wouldn't bother to multiply out $(m)(m-1)(m-2)$ etc. as you have done as it actually takes you away from showing that that equals $\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}$ as you hope to show.

The error:

$\frac{x^0}{0!(m-0)} + \frac{m x^1}{1!(m-1)} + \frac{m(m-1) x^2}{2!(m-2)}+ \frac{m(m-1)(m-2) x^3}{3!(m-3)}...$ is incorrect.

It should be:

$\frac{x^0}{0!} + \frac{m x^1}{1!} + \frac{m(m-1) x^2}{2!}+\frac{m(m-1)(m-2) x^2}{3!}...$

and

$m(m-1)(m-2)\cdots(m-(n-1)) = \frac{m!}{(m-n)!}$

And your conclusion.